# Large Object Volumetric Banding Isssues

Tags: rendering, volumetrics

I have a scene with an enclosing largeish object with a volume applied with this node setup.

[image]

All I've changed here is the density.

What I can't seem to figure out is the banding issue, at least I think this is a banding issue. I've tried changing the `Step Rate Render` and `Step Rate Viewport` and the `Max Steps` values but the issue persists.

If this is a banding issue. How can I smooth this out? Or is this just a fact of having such a low density?

If that's the case are there any techniques for using volumes on large objects?

[image]